# How to build a formula with several IF

Tags: formula, formula-field

How can I build a formula with several IF like this:

```
IF(((field_name  = 0)  || (field_name  = 1)), 'Test 1', '')
IF(((field_name  < 0)  || (field_name  = 2) || (field_name  = 3)), 'Test 2', '')
```

I tried using CASE but no success.

Comment: Your formulas will generally be significantly more readable if you remove all unneceessary parentheses and use `OR(expression1, expression2)` instead of `expression1 || expression2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look to following salesforce help [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)

you can build formula with several IFs like following

```
IF($User.City = "Napa", 0.0750, 
   IF($User.City = "Paso Robles", 0.0725, 
     IF($User.City = "Sutter Creek", 0.0725, 
       IF($User.City = "Los Olivos", 0.0750, 
         IF($User.City = "Livermore", 0.0875, null
         )
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

So in else part of each if statement start a new if statement.
Then your code would be like following

```
if(OR(field_name  = 0, field_name = 1), 'Test 1', 
   if(OR(field_name  < 0, field_name  = 2, field_name  = 3),'Test 2', '')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

IF(
((field_name  = 0)  || (field_name  = 1)), 'Test 1', IF( ((field_name  < 0)  || (field_name  = 2) || (field_name  = 3)), 'Test 2', '') )

Instead of using ,'' for your false return on the first if statement, you want to use your next if statement. That way it reads more like
if first option is false, if second option is false, then ''
instead of
if first option is false, then '' (and it just ends and doesn't look to the next statement)